# Where can I get people to learn "Elementary Number Theory" by Burton together?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I know this is not strictly a math question and will probably get closed, but I thought this is the best place to look for after failing in another place.

My undergraduate degree is in Computer Science, and learning abstract programming was really hard after 12 years of non creative, memory reliant education. The only reason I could learn a little bit of programming is that I had a class and classmates to share struggles and learn from.

I have always wanted to learn Mathematics, Computer Science was my second best choice. I have finally started to learn Number Theory, but for circumstances, I do not have a classroom I could attend.

And I am finding it takes a lot of growth which is difficult to face alone, especially while struggling with anxiety. I was wondering if anyone else was studying this book too, or if there is any online groups I could join. Or anything that would be helpful for beginners to go through the painful process of growth.

I am adding the tags I could think of, any relevant suggested tags would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reddit might be a possibility. There is a math section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this in a comment, but strictly speaking I'm not supposed to answer questions in the comments, so here it is:

Consider Reddit. If you google "reddit math" you will find a number of different subsections of Reddit that are devoted to various aspects of math, and I'm pretty sure I've seen posts where people try to assemble a group in order to study a textbook or subject together.

Good luck.

Comment: It helps to know there are people trying to assemble study groups in reddit. Thanks. I'll try that.